# How to grab a database column with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to grab some piece of data from my DB but all I could grab was the user id name and email. I've tried to grab the city and address but there is nothing shown and in console I receive undefined. Have anyone an idea where am I getting wrong?

app.js

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                    $rootScope.name = results.name;
                    $rootScope.email = results.email;
                    $rootScope.phone = results.phone;
                    console.log(results.phone);
                } else {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                    } else {
                        $location.path("/login");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

dashboard.html

```
UID: {{uid}}
<br/>NAME: {{name}}
<br/>E-MAIL: {{email}}
<br/>PHONE: {{phone}}
<br/>
```

sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers_auth` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

dbHandler.php

```
public function getSession(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    $sess = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
    {
        $sess["uid"] = $_SESSION['uid'];
        $sess["name"] = $_SESSION['name'];
        $sess["email"] = $_SESSION['email'];
        $sess["phone"] = $_SESSION['phone'];
    }
    else
    {
        $sess["uid"] = '';
        $sess["name"] = 'Guest';
        $sess["email"] = '';
        $sess["phone"] = '';
    }
    return $sess;
}
```

authentication.php

```
$app->get('/session', function() {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $session = $db->getSession();
    $response["uid"] = $session['uid'];
    $response["email"] = $session['email'];
    $response["name"] = $session['name'];
    echoResponse(200, $session);
});
```

Comment: It is seemly not possible to answer your question if you do not post the code for the backend. Could you post the code for this rest call "Data.get('session')"? and also possibly what you return for this call?

Comment: Have  look now @DuyNguyen

Comment: does your session stores the city and address? If not so you definitely need to get the user info from customers_auth table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to get the user info from customers_auth table edit `authentication.php`

```
$app->get('/session', function() {
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $session = $db->getSession();
    // depends on your db connector you should select the user required 
    //using the id: "$session['uid']".
    $user = $db->getOneRecord("select * from customers_auth where uid =".$session['uid']);
    $response["address"] = $user['address'];
    $response["city"] = $user['city'];
    $response["uid"] = $session['uid'];
    $response["email"] = $session['email'];
    $response["name"] = $session['name'];
    echoResponse(200, $response);
    });
```

Comment: if I update this I get this `GET http://localhost:8888/api/v1/session 500 (Internal Server Error)` and no info to display

Comment: did you get the $user from customers_auth table? If yes please share the code here

Comment: to have a better understand of the code have a look here http://www.angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/